# Knockout Mapping Plugin fail to bind Json collection from ASp.Net Webapi

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have the following code:

```
/*   Sample data received from an ASP.Net WebApi ajax call  */
var data = { [{"CodSeguro":676541,"NroSeguro":538178},{"CodSeguro":687069,"NroSeguro":577836]},{"CodSeguro":123,"NroSeguro":233]};

/*This function build the view model that will be shared by multiple pages*/
function getViewModel(data)
{
   return ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
}

var viewModel = getViewModel(data);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

My Html look like these:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>CodSeguro</th>
        <th>NroSeguro</th>
        <th>NroEndoso</th>        
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: ">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <span data-bind="text: CodSeguro"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span data-bind="text: NroSeguro"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span data-bind="text: NroEndoso"></span>
    </td>        
</tr>
```

Simply I dont know what to put after foreach in this line:

I really need to use the Mapping Plugin because there are a lot ob objects that i dont want to code in both places (js for knockout and c# in the service layer)

The fiddle is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Q6JE/

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `$data` to foreach:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $data">
```

But your `json` should be the following:

```
var data = [{"CodSeguro":676541,"NroSeguro":538178},{"CodSeguro":687069,"NroSeguro":577836},{"CodSeguro":123,"NroSeguro":233}];
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Q6JE/2/